# jQuery append and remove not working with dynamically columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with Ajax and jQuery, I am working on sorting (without data tables), I am getting correct result but just want to display sorting icons (up, down), I want whenever I click on any column (name or symbol) for sort then "down" icon should display and after click on "down" icon should replace with "up" and whenever I click on another column both icons should remove and display on another
column for sort like previous. How can I do this ? I tried with following code but icons appending (showing multiple times), where I am wrong?

Here is my html:

```
<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' id='postsList'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">Title</th>
            <th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">Symbol</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var timesClicked = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var column_name = $(this).attr("id");  
        timesClicked++;
           
        if (timesClicked % 2 == 1) { // after first click(even clicks)
            $('#'+column_name+'').append('<img src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/img/DownArrow.png"/>');   
            $('#'+column_name+'').remove('<img src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/img/UpArrow.png"/>');
            var order = "ASC";
        }else{
            var order = "DESC";   // after second click(odd clicks)
            $('#'+column_name+'').remove('<img src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/img/DownArrow.png"/>');   
            $('#'+column_name+'').append('<img src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/img/UpArrow.png"/>');
        };

        var arrow = '';  
        var PageNumber= $("#pagination").find("strong").html();
        $(".column_sort").removeClass("active");
        $.ajax({  
            url:'<?=base_url()?>/Main/fetch_details/', 
            method:"POST",  
            data:{column_name:column_name, order:order ,PageNumber:PageNumber},  
            success:function(data) {  
                $("#postsList tr:not(:first)").remove();
                $("#postsList2").show();
                $('#'+column_name+'').addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        }) 
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check [your browser's devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) console, I think you will see errors.

If you check [the docs for `.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), it removes the matched element - in your case, it is trying to remove the whole `<th>`.  If you pass a parameter, it should be a selector (not HTML), and it will filter the matched elements, not find nested elements.  Because you are passing HTML, the `.remove()` call is generating an error and failing, so the img is never removed.  Next time you click, a new one is added to the one that is already there.

So you really want something like:

```
$('#' + column_name + ' img').remove();
```

This will match the `<img>` element inside the `<th>`, and remove it.

Next problem - the order you add and remove elements is important.  Eg: for the first click, you add a down arrow.  If we now do the removal, the selector will match *any* image.  That means we'll remove both the old and the newly added images!

So we need to take care to 1) Remove the old image first; 2) Add a new image.

Here's a working snippet - click the Run button to see it in action.  I don't have your images of course, so instead of `<img>` elements I used `<span>`s, but the idea is exactly the same.

I also removed your AJAX code as that is not relevant to the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var timesClicked = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var column_name = $(this).attr("id");  
        timesClicked++;
           
        if (timesClicked % 2 == 1) {
            $('#' + column_name + ' span').remove();
            $('#' + column_name).append('<span> v</span>');   

        } else {
            $('#' + column_name + ' span').remove();
            $('#' + column_name).append('<span> ^</span>');
        };
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' id='postsList'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">Title</th>
            <th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">Symbol</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

PS: as an alternative to adding and removing elements on every click, it might be a neater solution to simply toggle visibility of elements already on the page.  Eg both arrow images are already on the page on page load, but with a "hidden" class.  Every click then just toggles that class on/off.  Maybe something like:

```
$('#' + column_name + ' img').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

How you display the arrow icons is up to you, for my example I simply used html entities. Wrap the up and down arrows into separate tags (span in my example) and include those within the TH tags for each column header.

```
<th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">
    Title
    <span>&uarr;</span><span>&darr;</span>
</th>
```

Hide all the spans by default and we'll target the others specifically by toggling between two other classes we'll add to the TH that already has column_sort class.

```
.column_sort{cursor:pointer}
.column_sort span{display:none;}
.sort_asc span:first-child{display:inline;}
.sort_desc span:nth-child(2){display:inline;}
```

Then for the javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(event){

    var $x = $(event.target);
    var ascending = $x.hasClass('sort_asc') ? true : false;

    // Remove arrows from any columns currently displaying them
    $('.column_sort.sort_asc').removeClass('sort_asc');
    $('.column_sort.sort_desc').removeClass('sort_desc');

    // Show the appropriate arrow
    if (ascending){     
        $x.addClass('sort_desc');   
    }else{
        $x.addClass('sort_asc');    
    }
  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/176hj8s0/

Since you already have logic in place to handle ascend and descend order, you can just piggyback off that to determine which class is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use fontawesome icons instead of img for display of up and down arrows. Here's a working example of how I do:
**Step 1. Use  tag after column name**

```
<tr>
<th>S.no</th>
<th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">
    Title <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon pr-10"></i>
</th>
<th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">
    Symbol <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon pr-10"></i>
</th>
```

**2.Jquery : First check which column is clicked and find class of icon tag and toggle it.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find(".fas").hasClass('fa-angle-down')) {
        $(this).find(".fas").removeClass('fa-angle-down');
        $(this).find(".fas").addClass('fa-angle-up');
    } else {
        $(this).find(".fas").removeClass('fa-angle-up');
        $(this).find(".fas").addClass('fa-angle-down');
    }
});
```